# Use Results from Table A in Table B

Tags: org-table

I am a beginner at `org-tables`, trying to use them for computing grades in a class I'm teaching. I have a table showing attendance records for a student, resulting in a mean that I'd like to use in a calculation in another table. Is it possible?

```
#+NAME: attendance
| time   | grade            |
|--------+------------------|
| week 1 | 1                |
| week 2 | 0                |
| week 3 | 1                |
|--------+------------------|
| grade  | :=vmean(@I..@-I) |

#+NAME: grades
| assignment | grade                            |
|------------+----------------------------------|
| attendance | [INSERT VMEAN FROM "attendance"] |
| paper 1    | 2.5                              |
| paper 2    | 2.5                              |
|------------+----------------------------------|
| final grade| :=vmean(@I..@-I)                 |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of section 3.5.1 of [org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References) there's a discussion of *remote references*, that's exactly what you're looking for:

> You may also reference constants, fields and ranges from a different
>   table, either in the current file or even in a different file.  The
>   syntax is
>
> ```
> remote(NAME-OR-ID,REF)
> ```
>
> where NAME can be the name of a table in the current file as set by a
>   ‘#+NAME: Name’ line before the table.

Here, you should simply name your first table and enter a formula using the remote reference in the chosen cell, `:=remote(attendance,@5$2)`.

```
#+NAME: attendance
| time   | grade |
|--------+-------|
| week 1 |     1 |
| week 2 |     4 |
| week 3 |     2 |
|--------+-------|
| grade  |     2 |
#+TBLFM: @5$2=vmean(@I..@-I)

#+NAME: grades
| assignment  |     grade |
|-------------+-----------|
| attendance  |         2 |
| paper 1     |       2.5 |
| paper 2     |       2.5 |
|-------------+-----------|
| final grade | 2.3333333 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2=remote(attendance,@5$2)::@5$2=vmean(@I..@-I)
```

To update the tables, use `M-x org-table-recalculate-buffer-tables` or `M-x org-table-iterate-buffer-tables` if you set up complex table dependencies.

Note that in this particular case, it's certainly better to use `@>$2` (last line, column 2): the `@5$2` won't be updated automatically in the 'grades' table if you later add lines to the 'attendance' table. Another, more general, way to avoid this kind of problem is to use [named references](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-features.html#Advanced-features).  Here, we name the cell `grade` so that we can reference it as `$grade`.

```
#+NAME: attendance2
|   | time   | grade |
|---+--------+-------|
|   | week 1 |     1 |
|   | week 2 |     4 |
|   | week 3 |     1 |
|---+--------+-------|
|   | grade  |     2 |
| ^ |        | grade |
#+TBLFM: @5$3=vmean(@I..@-I)

#+NAME: grades2
| assignment  |     grade |
|-------------+-----------|
| attendance  |         2 |
| paper 1     |       2.5 |
| paper 2     |       2.5 |
|-------------+-----------|
| final grade | 2.3333333 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2=remote(attendance2,$grade)::@5$2=vmean(@I..@-I)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I've refined the question above based on your advice here ... I hope that isn't considered impolite (I'm somewhat new to Stack Exchange).

Comment: @StevenArntson I expanded my answer to include details.  If this solves your problem I suggest you revert your question to its first revision so that question and answer "agree".

Comment: Thank you. One part of the problem ended up being that I hadn't put `:=` before `remote(...)`. It is now working well!

Comment: @StevenArntson Beware if you later add lines to the 'grades' table. I added info on how to avoid such problems.

Comment: Using `named references` is going to be very useful for me, thank you.